# In Gradle, associating task with a dependency configuration

Tags: java, android, gradle

How can a task be associated to a specific dependency configuration?

If I look the **23.5. Dependency management** ([gradle java plugin official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)) section part, it states that, for example, *compileTestJava task* use *testCompile* configuration.

I just wanted to know how I could achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

gradle is creating these configurations automatically; 
if you define a `sourceSet`, a bunch of things gets created (by convention):

```
sourceSets {
   thing
}
```

will define configurations: `thingCompile, thingRuntime`
tasks: `compileThingJava, processThingResources, thingClasses`

you might want to look at: `gradle tasks --all` and `gradle dependencies`

if you want to add dependencies to these configurations
the most preferable to use the generated ones

you may of course create your own configuration and extend from that: `configurations { thingCompile.extendsFrom(myConfig) }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this example, the task `compileThingJava` will use `thingCompile`? How do I know that?

Comment: yes it will use that...there are some notes about this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html see 23.2

Comment: I've already seen it :) thank you by the way.
However, at the _23.5_ section, you could see that `compileJava` task is using the `compile` dependency configuration, but why is that? Where is this kind of bound defined?