# Gradle binding dependency configuration with a task

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I'm completely new with Gradle. For beginning, I am trying to create a build script for simple console Java application, without using java plugin. There are only two dependencies in my code from maven repository.
So, my build contains one task, which extends JavaCompile, in which I specify classpath, destination, ect. 
My project doesn't apply java plugin, therefore I need to create dependency configuration by my own, like this:

```
    configurations {
      myCompile {
      desciprtion = 'my own compile dependency configuration'
      transitive = true
      }
 }
```

Then I can bind dependencies on this configuration:

```
dependencies {
myCompile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.7'
myCompile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.7'
}
```

As far as i understand, after that I must bind those configuration with my compile action, but I can't figure out how. Can someone point this out to me?
Any help will be really appreciated)

P.S. I have read this [In Gradle, associating task with a dependency configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123649/in-gradle-associating-task-with-a-dependency-configuration), and there is mentioned sourcesets. So, I can create sourceset myThing, and task with configuration will be created for me? Will this work without java plugin?

P.P.S. I want to achieve this simple task without plugins just for the purpose of learning Gradle, and it's basic tools :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I used this code to compile project without java plugin:

```
task resolveCompileDependency(type: Copy) {
    //download libraries specified in dependency configuration
    def lib_files = configurations.myCompile.resolve()
    //print names of downloaded files and copy to build directory (optional)
    lib_files.each {File file ->
        println file.name
    }
    from lib_files
    into 'build/classes'
    outputs.files(lib_files)
}
```

And compile task is just ordinary JavaCompile task, which depends on resolveCompileDependency.
 Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

First create the compilation task using an exec task type, see [DSL refreence for Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).

When you create your compilation task, you can get a reference to the configuration using getAsPath(), see [API doc for FileCollection](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#getAsPath())

```
configurations.myCompile.getAsPath()
```

But seriously, I **do** recommend that you apply the java plugin for this.

If you feel the need tor a quick beginner course, try [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFUEb7pLLXw).

Comment: Thanks for the link!Why use Exec type for compilation, not JavaCompile?

Comment: And in Task documentation ( https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html ) there are listed objects which can be used as a dependency, but that seem to relate only to dependency to other tasks (paragraph Task Dependencies and Task Ordering)

Comment: The exec can be used IF you want to write the whole compilation yourself, but as you say there is no real need for it.

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to write compilation etc WITHOUT applying the java plugin (since you wrote: 'without plugins'). Which seemed quite odd but perhaps a good exercise.